# Is it possible to enum and timestamp using pgp.helpers.update?

Tags: javascript, node.js, pg-promise

#### Expected behavior

`pgp.helpers.update` should be able to update enum and timestamp.

I have a table ("myTable") it has following columns

```
id (varchar)
comparator (type enum named as comparator_type with values ['eq', 'ne', 'leq', 'geq', 'gt', 'lt'])
updatedAt (timestamp)
```

The entries to update are

```js
entries = [
    {
        id: "someId",
         comparator: "gt",
        updatedAt: new Date().toISOString()
    }
]
// Using pgp.helpers.update
const updateQuery = pgp.helpers.update(entries, ["?id", "comparator", "updatedAt"], "myTable") + '  WHERE v.id = t.id';
console.log(updateQuery);

// printing it here for reference
/**
* update "myTable" as t set "comparator"=v."comparator","updatedAt"=v."updatedAt" from (values('someId','gt','0.92','2023-02-17T19:46:38.723Z')) as v("id","comparator","updatedAt") WHERE v.id = t.id
**/
```

#### Actual behavior

It is not updating `type enum` and `timestamp`. This is following error I'm getting

#### Steps to reproduce

The following code is being used to run the generated query

```js
await pgDb.any(updateQuery);
```

The following error I'm getting

```json
{
    "name": "error",
    "severity": "ERROR",
    "code": "42804",
    "hint": "You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.",
    "position": "112",
    "file": "parse_target.c",
    "line": "587",
    "routine": "transformAssignedExpr",
    "query": "<query above>"
}
```

When I tried to run the same query in Dbever, it starts to give me the following,

```
ERROR: column "comparator" is of type comparator_type but expression is of type text. Hint: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
```

if I change the `"comparator"=v."comparator"`  to `"comparator"='gt'`, then it given me next error that is

```
ERROR: column "updatedAt" is of type timestamp without time zone but expression is of type text. Hint: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
```

SO clearly, the query generated by pg-promise is not working.

#### Environment

- Version of pg-promise: 11.2.0
- OS type (Linux/Windows/Mac): Linux
- Version of Node.js: v16.19.0

###### Link of gihub issue I created - https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise/issues/866

Comment: The error tells you that you need type casting, yet you are not using any. [Column](https://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/helpers.Column.html) supports casting.

Comment: If you have figured it out, you can post your own answer here ;)

Comment: @vitaly-t sure, I'll post the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used pg.helpers.ColumnSet() to resolve my query. It supports casting and worked like charm.

PS: I would like to know what's the difference between Column and ColumnSet.

```js
entries = [
    {
        id: "someId",
        comparator: "gt",
        updatedAt: new Date().toISOString()
    }
]
const cs = new pg.helpers.ColumnSet([
    "?id",
    {
       name: "comparator",
       cast: "comparator_type"
    }, 
    {
       name: "updatedAt",
       cast: "timestamp"
    }
]);

// Using pgp.helpers.update
const updateQuery = pgp.helpers.update(entries, cs, "myTable") + '  WHERE v.id = t.id';
```

Comment: [ColumnSet](https://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/helpers.ColumnSet.html) gets a list of [Column](https://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/helpers.Column.html)-s. When columns are passed in as simple objects, those are converted into [Column](https://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/helpers.Column.html)-s.